# Express English sentence in predicate calculus

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

Trying express,"Someone in your school has visited Japan."

I'm wondering why the given answer is:$\exists x(A(x) \land P(x))$,where A(x) denotes,"x is in your school" and P(x) denotes,"x has visited Japan,domain of x consists of all people in the world;

But not $\exists x(A(x) \rightarrow P(x))$?
Since if there's someone not in your school,he's visited Japan could be whether true or false.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that no one in your school has visited Japan, but somewhere there is some person $a$ who has visited Japan. Then $P(a)$ is true, so $A(a)\to P(a)$ is true, and therefore $\exists x\big(A(x)\to P(x)\big)$ is true, **even though no one in your school has visited Japan**. Thus, the expression $\exists x\big(A(x)\to P(x)\big)$ definitely does not capture the English sentence. (In fact it really doesn’t matter whether $a$ has visited Japan, since the implication $A(a)\to P(a)$ is automatically true whenever $A(a)$ is false, i.e., whenever $a$ is not in your school.)

The expression $\exists x\big(A(x)\land P(x)\big)$, however, does: it says that there is someone who has visited Japan **and** is in your school, which is exactly the semantic content of the sentence *Someone in your school has visited Japan*.

Comment: Actually, $A(a) \to P(a)$ is true if $a$ is not in your school, even if $a$ has not visited Japan.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Of course, but I thought that it might be a little more immediately helpful if I used a case not quite so far removed from the everyday notion of _if ... then_. Still, it might not be a bad idea to mention that.